# How to show two different labels of a particular vector layer with the help of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am working under a government project in Kolkata with QGIS.

I want to show two different labels of a particular vector layer. just like we can show two different labels in Arc GIS with the help of Append option.

Suppose I want to show  Male population Numbers and Female  population numbers on a District vector layer, so how it can be possible? please tell me the option of this Software (QGIS).

Actually i am able to show one label on a layer but how to show two labels?

Answer (score 6):

That's possible using "expression based labeling" which should be part of the upcoming 1.8 release and is part of the current developer version.

Here's an introduction written by the developer: http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/expression-based-labeling/

You'll find an editor with preview function that should make it straight forward to create advanced labels.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use both the new labeller and the old at the same time, and have two labels that way. Offset one to the left and the other to right.

In underdark's answer, you should understand that || is concatenate. You can use this in an expression for dynamic labelling, or you could carry out a one time concatenate directly in the attribute table. The workflow of this creates a new column which combines your two pieces of label data into one string. Depending on the use of capitals or a separator you will then display the string as one label with either one of the labelling tools currently available in QGIS.

See also 
[Which labelling tool/engine in QGIS will be supported in the long term?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23062/which-labelling-tool-engine-in-qgis-will-be-supported-in-the-long-term/23063#23063)