# Is it possible to add multiple labels for each element of a layer?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to add different labels for the elements of a layer.
Example:

1. One label with the number inside the marker.
2. Another label above the marker with the name of the element, different typography and size and with scale rule so that it is not displayed if the scale is above 20.000.
3. Etc..

As far as I have seen in my QGIS 2.6.1 I am only able to add one unique label.

Is there any way to add more than one?

Comment: Hope it will help http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25284/how-to-show-two-different-labels-of-a-particular-vector-layer-with-the-help-of-q?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Don't think this is possible as of yet. A workaround could be to:

- Create a copy of your layer
- Edit the symbology of the copied layer to make the features transparent (ie. no visualisation)
- Add layers to the copied layer and edit the placement options so that it doesn't overlap the labels from the original layer.

Hope this helps and hopefully others can also advise!