# How to make the coordinates of point appears as labels?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, labeling, coordinates, point

I am working on a school project that requires us to have a map with the points indicating different station with its coordinates appearing as a label.  I just don't know how to do it?

I think it could be possible but we just started using QGIS so I know very little.

Answer (score 6):

You can click on the equation icon beside the `label with` to enter a complex label.

Then, you can access the geometry coordinates using `$x` and `$y`. You can also concatenate text using `||`

To display the X and Y, you could use an expression like:

```
$x || ' - ' || $y
```

[image]

Comment: Note that if you want to display latitude and longitude, the x coordinate is longitude and the y coordinate is latitude. So if you want coordinates displayed as `lat, long` use the formula `$y || ', ' || $x`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool "add coordinates to points" and then you can, in the new layer, use multiline labels. These links could help you : 
https://anitagraser.com/2011/06/15/multi-line-labels-in-qgis/
[How to show two different labels of a particular vector layer with the help of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25284/how-to-show-two-different-labels-of-a-particular-vector-layer-with-the-help-of-q?rq=1)